# C++: Are lvalue and rvalue interchangeable?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
void g(int& i) {
    std::cout << "g(int&)" << std::endl;
}
void g(int&& i) {
    std::cout << "g(int&&)" << std::endl;
}
void f(int&& i) {
    g(i);
}
int main() {
    f(3);  // g(int&)
}
```

As you can see, the parameter `i` in the `f` function is an rvalue reference, so when it calls `g(i)`, the corresponding `g` function which takes an rvalue reference should be called(i.e. the result should be `g(int&&)`), but this is not the case. Actually, `g(int& i)` was called. Why?

My guess is that when we are inside the `f` function, `i` becomes an lvalue instead of an rvalue, is that correct? Are lvalue and rvalue interchangeable?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. You have the `std::move` every step of the way towards the final destination.

Comment: While i in f function binds to rvalue, it is a lvalue (it has a name), so, when you use it to call another function, it will binds to lvalue unless you ask it to become a rvalue (`std::move`)